# How to return value from Whiptail --yesno

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi2, whiptail

I'm creating a shell script to run on my raspberry pi. Along the way I'm trying to simplify some repeated code and I'd like to make a wrapper for the whiptail function like below.

```
function yesno() {
  answer=$(whiptail --yesno "$1" 0 0 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
  echo $answer
}
```

This function does not echo anything and I'm wondering if my syntax is wrong. The function does trigger when entering `yesno "Your question"` in my terminal.

Also echoing `$?` does not help since it does not seem to catch any data when not using `return` in a function.

When trying to use `return` I get an error saying that I need to return an integer.

I've had success running this function in a `if` statement and was convinced it did return a 0 or 1.

```
if whiptail --yesno "Are you sure you want to clear all SSH keys from the list?" 0 0; then
  # Do stuff
fi
```

**Anyone knows how to pour the output of the --yesno whiptail function I've shown into a variable?**

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you meant something like

```
#!/bin/bash
function yesno() {
  answer=$(whiptail --yesno "$1" 0 0 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3; echo $?)
  echo "Answer <$answer>"
}

yesno "Hello world"
```

which prints **`$?`** in the subshell (0=yes, 1=no).